# How to select only visible elements from scrollable container?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is it possible to get list of visible elements in scrollable container? When using a scroll, the number of elements visible on the screen obviously changes - for this reason, add particular class to the last two visible elements is extremely difficult.

Do you have any ideas?

```
  <div class="scrollable-container">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{ item?.Name }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listening for `scroll` events on the document and then determining the position of the bounding rectangle relative to the viewport will let you determine if and where an element is visible:

Simply replace `div#question` with the locator of the element you are interested in.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    var rect = document.querySelector('div#question').getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.top > window.innerHeight) {
        console.log("Element below viewport");
    } else if (rect.top > 0 && rect.top < window.innerHeight && rect.bottom > window.innerHeight) {
        console.log("Element partly visible at bottom");
    } else if (rect.top > 0 && rect.top < window.innerHeight && rect.bottom < window.innerHeight) {
        console.log("Element fully visible");
    } else if (rect.top < 0 && rect.bottom > 0) {
        console.log("Element partly visible at top");
    } else if (rect.bottom < 0) {
        console.log("Element above viewport");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most performant way I know of to do it in native JavaScript. The concept is the same for Angular, but you'll need to make some changes and will want to make others. I'll cover that after the example.

You may want to view the example in full screen.

(Note that more than two items could be highlighted if part of a third is partially visible. Once you read about the `threshold` option below, you can play around with it to tweak this behavior).

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.scrollable-container');

const options = { 
  root: list,
  rootMargin: '-150px 0px 0px 0px',
  threshold: 0
};

function onIntersectionChange(entries) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) 
      entry.target.classList.add('highlighted');
    else 
      entry.target.classList.remove('highlighted');
  });
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersectionChange, options);

{
  const listItems = list.children;
  for (let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    observer.observe(listItems[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
.scrollable-container {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px 0;  
}

.highlighted {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable-container">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9</div>
  <div class="item">Item 10</div>
  <div class="item">Item 11</div>
  <div class="item">Item 12</div>
  <div class="item">Item 13</div>
  <div class="item">Item 14</div>
  <div class="item">Item 15</div>
  <div class="item">Item 16</div>
  <div class="item">Item 17</div>
  <div class="item">Item 18</div>
  <div class="item">Item 19</div>
  <div class="item">Item 20</div>
</div>
```

I'm using the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to listen for intersections between the items in the list and the bottom portion of the list container element. Every time one of the observed items changes from "intersecting" to "not intersecting", the API calls my handler method.

To set this up, I've provided an object called `options` to the observer with the following options set:

- `root`: the list container.
- `rootMargin`: an offset  from the actual bounding box of the `root`. Think of this like shrinking the actual size of the target `root` down by some margin. Here I've decreased the size by 100px from the top. If an element goes above this imaginary line in the list container, it will no longer be considered "intersecting".
- `threshold`: how much of an element (on a scale from 0 to 1.0) must be inside the `root` to be considered "intersecting". While 0 is the default, I've included it for clarity. Here 0 means that if any pixels at all enter `root`, the element is considered "intersecting" until the last pixels leave. If it were set to 1.0, then all the pixels in the element would have to be in `root` before it was considered "intersecting" and it would be considered "not intersecting" as soon as one pixel left `root`.

Next I've created the callback that will be executed every time any of the observed elements changes from "intersecting" to "not intersecting" and vice-versa. `entries` is the collection of elements whose status changed. If the element is now intersecting `root`, we add the appropriate CSS class. If it is no longer intersecting `root`, we remove the class.

Finally, I create the observer and register each item in the list as an entry that should be observed. The registration is inside a function block to keep `listItems` available only while we need it. It will fall out of scope once the elements are registered.

---

About Angular, there is a change you must make:

- Because you're using `ngFor`, you cannot register items until the template is rendered. That means your component will need to implement `AfterViewInit` and register items with the observer inside `ngAfterViewInit()`.

There are also changes you may want to make:

- Angular has access to directives like `@ViewChild` that make selecting items from the template safer than using native `querySelector`/`getElementById` approaches, particularly as your template is rerendered.
- Angular uses TypeScript, so you'll want to type your variables for ease of testing, error checking, etc. Because the Intersection Observer API is native JavaScript, there are existing TypeScript types for it; you don't need to write your own.
- Angular is set up to work well with proper rxjs observables and you will likely improve performance even more by working with them to e.g. debounce when the handler function is called, observe when specific items change intersection status, etc. There are a few good blog posts about using the Intersection Observer API with Angular that cover these kinds of topics.

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c5uawn?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with a least-effort port into Angular (meaning only the needed change was made).